# Visual Studio C#: Changing Form background image when moving cursor to a specific coordinate causing out of memory. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to write a application that changing its background image when moving the cursor to a specific location (coordinate).
Example:

- Moving the cursor to the right of the screen then change background to A.png, moving the cursor to the left of the screen then change background to B.png.

I wrote a code, It worked but I have some problems:

- The background image keeps blinking (like it continuously loads that image)
- After a while, it crashes and I receive an "out of memory" error form
  Visual Studio Debug mode.

How can I fix this?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread ChangeBackgroundThread = new Thread(ChangeBackground);
            ChangeBackgroundThread.Start();

        }

        private void ChangeBackground()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (MousePosition.X <= 960)
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("F:/test", "A.png"));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("F:/test", "B.png"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should cache the images and reuse the references.

Comment: You have to trigger an event when X coordinate is bigger than 960. You can leave a default background (when x<960). This should be the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: This also shouldn't be in a CPU hogging (while true?!) thread.  Wire up the [MouseMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove?view=netframework-4.8) event and only change the image when necessary as mentioned by others.  You can use a different type variable to track what the current background is.  Another approach would be to use a WinForms Timer and only check every xxx milliseconds (again, only changing it when you actually need to).

Comment: Thank you guys very much! Using all of your suggestion, the problem was solved! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider trying something like this out:

```
private Image ImgA;
private Image ImgB;
private Boolean? BackgroundA = true;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImgA = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("F:/test", "A.png"));
    ImgB = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("F:/test", "B.png"));
    this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    SetBackground();
}

private void SetBackground()
{
    Boolean curA = (MousePosition.X <= 960);
    if (!BackgroundA.HasValue || BackgroundA.Value != curA)
    {
        BackgroundA = curA;
        this.BackgroundImage = BackgroundA.Value ? ImgA : ImgB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! This work too!
So clean!
I have made a mess while fixing my code by my self xD, I will try this code.
Thank you so much, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Change the background only when it really-REALLY needs to change. When is that? When previous coordinate was for the old background, and new coordinate is for the new. So, you have to save the old coordinate, to be able to compare it to the new.

Also, do not load the the image every single time you want to change it. Load both images only once on program start, and pick one from memory when you want to change the background.

Also, instead of `while(true)` loop you should subscribe to MouseMove event, so that you don't run one processor core to 100% usage. Shouts to @Idle_Mind

Comment: Thanks, using your suggestion, i have fixed that!
I wrote a loop that check if the cursor leave the old area or not,
after that the problems was solved!
Thank you very much! :)